# use htaccess to remove spaces from URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to remove spaces from URL to be website compatible

Given:

```
https://example.com/About Resting Days.pdf
```

Return:

```
https://example.com/AboutRestingDays.pdf
```

---

```
https://example.com/About Resting Days.pdf

RewriteRule ^([^\s%20]*)(?:\s|%20)+(.*)$ $1$2 [L,R]

https://example.com/AboutResting Days.pdf
```

Only works for first instance. It appears it needs to loop

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^([^\s%20]*)(?:\s|%20)+(.*)$ $1$2 [L,R]
> ```

This will "loop" - but it will trigger an external redirect "loop" until all the spaces have been replaced (certainly undesirable if you have URLs with more than two spaces). However, there are other "errors" with this rule:

- There is no slash prefix on the substitution string, so it will result in a malformed redirect, unless you also have an appropriate `RewriteBase` directive defined.
- `[^\s%20]` - The `%`, `2` and `0` characters inside the character class are seen as separate literal characters. It's not `%20` (a URL encoded *space*).
- The `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches against the %-decoded URL-path, so attempting to match against `%20` is superfluous anyway (unless the requested URL is doubly URL-encoded).

With regards to the "loop"... you can iteratively remove all the spaces with an internal rewrite (as opposed to an external redirect) and only issue an external redirect once all the spaces have been removed.

For example, at the top of the root `.htaccess` file, try something like the following:

```
RewriteRule ^(\S+)\s(\S+\s.+)$ $1$2 [N]
RewriteRule ^(\S+)\s(\S+)$ /$1$2 [R=302,L]
```

The first rule matches a URL that contains *more* than 1 *space* and removes the first space. The `N` flag causes the rewrite engine to start over immediately (effectively a recursive loop), passing back the rewritten URL. The rule is then reprocessed until all but the last space is removed.

The second rule then matches a URL that contains just 1 space (the last space if the previous rule has been triggered) and triggers an immediate external redirect to remove the last space.

The `\s` (lowercase `s`) shorthand character class matches any *space* character. Whereas `\S` (uppercase `S`) matches any non-space character.

I've made some additional assumptions, based off your example:

- The URL-path does not start or end with a space. (Although I'm not sure that a URL-path could technically *end* with a space anyway?)
- There are only single spaces, interspersed with non-space characters. ie. There are no contiguous sequences of more than one space.

---

Having said all that, if your URLs only ever contain at most a handful of spaces then you could just hardcode the individual rules for 5, 4, 3, 2 and 1 *spaces* respectively. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^(\S+)\s(\S+)\s(\S+)\s(\S+)\s(\S+)\s(\S+)$ /$1$2$3$4$5$6 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^(\S+)\s(\S+)\s(\S+)\s(\S+)\s(\S+)$ /$1$2$3$4$5 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^(\S+)\s(\S+)\s(\S+)\s(\S+)$ /$1$2$3$4 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^(\S+)\s(\S+)\s(\S+)$ /$1$2$3 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^(\S+)\s(\S+)$ /$1$2 [R,L]
```